# How to add an Frame inside another frame in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame

I am trying to add a frame inside the another frame using  tkinter, but the frame is not added:

**Code:**

```
lframe=Frame(r,width=1000,height=650,relief='raise',bd=8).pack(side=LEFT)

rframe=Frame(r,width=350,height=650,relief='raise',bd=8).pack(side=RIGHT)



lframe1=Frame(lframe,width=1000,height=100,bd=8,relief='raise').pack(side= TOP)

lframe2=Frame(lframe,width=1000,height=55,bd=8,relief='raise').pack(side=TOP)

rframe1=Frame(rframe,width=350,height=215,relief='raise',bd=8).pack(side=TOP)

rframe2=Frame(rframe,width=350,height=415,relief='raise',bd=8).pack(side=TOP)

r.mainloop()
```

**its shows the following output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What caused your problem?**

`lframe` is worth `None` and does not refer to the frame instance you created in anyway. Why so?

Because `pack()`, `gird()` and `place()` layout managers are functions that return nothing. So when you write:

```
lframe=Frame(r,width=1000,height=650,relief='raise',bd=8).pack(side=LEFT)
```

You are clearly getting None from `pack(side=LEFT)`

**How to fix your problem?**

Simply follow this principle whenever you create a widget: create then position (In your case, you create and position the widget on the same time). I personally refer to this principle as [The SaYa idiom](https://www.begueradj.com/tkinter-saya-idiom.html). This means the previous line of code should be written as follows:

```
lframe=Frame(r,width=1000,height=650,relief='raise',bd=8)
lframe.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Apply this idiom to all your widgets and that will save you from some troubles.